# How can I use has_shortcode() including the attribute value?

Tags: wordpress, attributes, shortcode

I want to use has_shortcode() to find out whether a certain shortcode using a certain value as attribute is being used on a WordPress page. The shortcode/attribute combination I'm looking for is [formidable id=11]. has_shortcode($content, 'formidable') only tells me whether the shortcode formidable is used, but not which value for the id. Background: I'm trying to find out whether a certain Formidable form is on my content.